# Can I use a generic class AND a struct in the same constructor?

Tags: c#, generics

My desire for a ServiceResponse object is that I want to give them back the "thing" they are requesting.  This could be a List of Foo, just a Foo or just about anything as long as it is a class with a parameterless constructor.  However, there are times when I want to return a byte array (byte[]) and that is not allowed because it is a struct and apparently has no parameterless constructor.

```
public class ServiceResponse<T> : ServiceResponse where T : new() {

    [DataMember]
    public T Result { get; set; }

    public ServiceResponse() {
        this.WasSuccessful = false;
        this.Result = new T();
        this.Exceptions = new List<CountyException>(); ;
    }

    public ServiceResponse(bool wasSuccessful, List<CountyException> exceptions, T result) {
        this.Result = result;
        this.WasSuccessful = wasSuccessful;
        this.Exceptions = exceptions;
    }
}
```

If I adjust the declaration line to the following:

```
public class ServiceResponse<T> : ServiceResponse where T : new(), struct {
```

I get the following error:

> byte[] must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter T in the generic type method ServiceResponse

So the question is, can I have a single class that takes a T that is a generic or a struct?  Even if I have to see what type it is when it comes in would be fine I suppose.

Comment: Note that the constraints you put in the `where` are in AND, not OR. If you say `where T : new(), struct` you're asking for a T that is both a struct and has a parameterless constructor (which is redundant, as all structs have a parameterless constructor)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella good to know.  Is there an OR?

Comment: not really, I'm afraid. You could remove all checks on T and use reflection (look for [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) ) to create your type... However, it looks like you are trying to build a God-class that can act as a factory for almost any type, which is a known anti-pattern, so maybe I would try reconsidering your design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get rid of the `new()` constraint. *All* structs have a parameterless constructor as far as C# is concerned, so you can still use `new T()` with just a constraint of `where T : struct`.

Note, however, that `byte[]` is *not* a value type, so it would not satisfy that constraint.

Any reason you don't want to just leave it unconstrained and not bother setting `Result` within the constructor? (Or set it to `default(T)` if you really want to.)

Comment: your answer intrigued me so I went with it.  I removed the constraint and it compiled.  While testing, I had a line of code that did:  ServiceResponse<List<int>> Test = new ServiceResponse<List<int>>();  Then the next line was Test.Result.AddRange(new List<int> { DateTime.Now.Year - 2, DateTime.Now.Year - 1 ... });  That has worked until now since the List<int> is not instantiated in the ServiceResponse class.  I do not want to have my people need to instantiate their Response values if possible.  Can I get around this?

Comment: @Grandizer: Why don't you want to instantiate the values? I'd use type inference to provide the value and infer the type, e.g. `var response = ServiceResponse.ForValue(new List<int>());`. I think that's cleaner than requiring a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I will attempt your suggesting tomorrow.  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not the `struct`. In fact, `byte[]` is a reference type (hint: Array). The problem is, that `byte[]` doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, just as the error message tells you